# How do I investigate a "style sheet could not be loaded" message in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

How do I investigate a "style sheet could not be loaded" message in Firefox?  This message appears as a red bar below the page contents and above the developer tools.  How do I find out what file the browser is referring to?  I'm running version 46.0 on Linux Mint 17.3.

**Update**

If I look at the console of the developer's tools in Firefox, it shows all the css files and says "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" against each file.

**Another Update**

This error bar comes and goes, it is not consistent for a particular page.

Comment: Does this occur on other browsers such as Chrome or IE?

Comment: I don't use either of those browsers.

Comment: I have updated my answer below for you re: your updated question.

Comment: Are you suggesting, in a round about way, that if you can't find the bug in one browser try using another?

Comment: No, I'm saying you *can't* claim it's a browser bug until you can show that this "bug"/"feature" *doesn't* appear in other browsers. Otherwise the problem can just as easily be your coding or some middleware issue.

Comment: What is the URL of the website? I can look at it and probably diagnose it in minutes....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens almost always when CSS is gziped, but server returns Content-Length of **not** compressed resource. Seen this happen when using mod_deflate with mod_fastcgi. This is server side bug, not firefox.

Comment: Is it worth replacing mod_fastcgi with mod_fcgid?  I'm only running localhost at the moment, so if it is not detrimental... does it matter?

Comment: @tyebillion I do experience the same problem with `mod_fcgid`. So I assume the answer is no.

Comment: But I am just opening my `index.html` which is linked to the stylesheet, there is no server or client side host involved just plain html and css and I am still getting this error. What should I do?

Comment: This answer is invalid since the issue still occurs with all server-side compression disabled

Answer (score 14):

This may be a very specific edge case, but I had this exact same error with no indication as to which style sheet Firefox was complaining about. It turns out that it was the Ad Blocker that I was using. When I disabled the ad blocker and reloaded my page, the error went away.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

> ## Update Notice:
>
> Firebug is out of date, instead of firebug you want to be using [**Firefox Developer Edition**](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) which has Firebug-type diagnostics and tools built in.

[Get Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or otherwise view the page source code (right click on it on Firefox and choose View Source) and click through on each .css stylesheet as referenced in the `<head>` section of the HTML page. One or more of these will return an Error 404 or some other error.

Each CSS sheet is in a `<link>` element in the Head of the HTML.

**Example:**

viewing the source code to this page will give a pile of code, in the `<head>` section is the `<link>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage"> 
<head> 
 ...
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=8c7d44a438e6"> 
...
 </head>
```

This shows that there is a style sheet in the link element, and for your page/site if you click through all of these (there may be multiple ones) and find the one that gives you the specific error.

**UPDATE:**

> (Update) if I look at the console of the developer's tools in Firefox, it shows all the css files and says "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" against each file.

Therefore you should be looking *in* each of your CSS and related documents to see which document is linking out to an unreachable resource.

Comment: I don't understand, why isn't it listed in Firefox's Console or Network panels?  I mean it is Firefox relaying the error.

Comment: (sigh), [get Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Use firebug. What does it tell you? The do the points suggested in my answer, such as looking *in* each of your CSS files for the external content and then checking if that content can be opened directly via the browser window. @tyebillion

Comment: No where else do I see the error, not in Firefox developer tools, Firebug or Chrome developer tools.  As the error has disappeared now I think it was an old error that Firefox had not cleared.  Perhaps closing the developer tool panel and re-opening has cleared the error.

Comment: Firebug is outdated. It says so on the [Firebug home page](http://getfirebug.com/). So this answer is, too.

Comment: @twigmac this answer was posted in May 2016 and so that was 9 months ago, things change..... firebug still works, it just is no longer being updated....

Comment: @Martin I acknowledge that the answer was helpful when it was written. In my experience Firebug is getting buggy because it's not maintained anymore and I think the answer should be updated to emphasize more the other solution, which is to review the source code or look at the dev tools console.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for `style sheet could not be loaded` is "active mixed content" in combination with HTTPS. I.e. if your HTML code is loaded over HTTPS, but references a CSS that is delivered over HTTP, Firefox will block the CSS file. The blocking will cause an explanatory entry in the Web console. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content for more information.

The blocking will also happen if the request for the CSS file is answered via HTTPS with a redirect and the redirect URL uses HTTP. And Google Chromium will also block active mixed content over HTTP and make an entry in its Javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error from this stackexchange page, got the red line in firebug console. It pointed to the link https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=743e70f26396 so I checked the page source copy/pasted the link into a new tab and hit enter. Firefox screamed Security issue certificate error, So I just added an exception and the CSS loads.  This error did not appear in Chrome or IE.

Easy fix.

Comment: Your link is broken