# Mozilla Firefox doesn't load Google fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api, google-fonts

I'm using `Cairo` google font in my project. Everything works fine in chrome but when I tried Mozilla Firefox, the font didn't load.

I got an alert message that says: "Style sheet could not be loaded."

I'm using this method to load Google fonts:

In the head:

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

In the CSS file:

```css
font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
```

- I tried to add `@font-face` and self-hosted the font.
- I checked `Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above` in Mozilla  Firefox Settings > General > Fonts > Advanced
- I also used this method to load the fonts :

```html
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
</style>
```

but this didn't solve the problem.

I tested the website on other devices and I still getting the same problem.

Comment: Turn off your Ad Blocker. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989220/how-do-i-investigate-a-style-sheet-could-not-be-loaded-message-in-firefox)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I investigate a "style sheet could not be loaded" message in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989220/how-do-i-investigate-a-style-sheet-could-not-be-loaded-message-in-firefox)

Comment: @Raptor Thank you for sharing the link, but this didn't solve my problem. The font is rendered now but it's quite pixelated, and it slightly affects the width of the containers. I solved this problem by writing Firefox specific CSS code.